# Material Styles are not being applied in angular app after being correctly imported

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

My problem is that my stylesheet are getting correctly included in the webpage, but the styles are not getting applied. The problem is as follows:

I am trying to use Angular material, i've correctly setup my app as was shown in the [begginer's guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started).

I inspected my app and the stylesheets are correctly getting imported (included). However, the styles are not being appplied.

A Screenshot of my network tab:
[image: Network tab screenshot]

the application tab also tells that stylesheets have been applied:
[image: applcation tab screenshot]

I have tried to include the theme designs via three ways:

1) using `@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";` in styles.css

2) using link element in index.html like: `<link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">` (it didnot worked out)

3) so i made an assets folder and placed all my files there like:
[image: assets folder structure]

and then in my angular-cli.json file i have gulp configured like:

```
"assets": [
    { "glob": "**/*", "input": "./assets/Images/", "output": "./assets/Images/" },
    { "glob": "**/*", "input": "./assets/StyleSheets/", "output": "./assets/StyleSheets/" },
    { "glob": "**/*", "input": "./assets/Javascript/", "output": "./assets/Javascript/" },
    { "glob": "**/*", "input": "./assets/Json/", "output": "./assets/Json/" },
    "favicon.ico"
  ]
```

and i included my stylesheet afterwards like: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/StyleSheets/deeppurple-amber.css">` and it worked.

However, when i tried to use the styles like:
`<button md-raised-button color="primary">Click me!</button>`

the styles were not getting applied.

please help me to find out what wrong am i doing.

And let me know if you need the repository link for re-producing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it putting the style in the angular-cli.json file:

```
"styles": [
    "styles.scss",
    "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
],
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a Bug in Angular Material I was able to fix it by remove '~' in import 
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
to 
@import "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";

Comment: I tried what you did specified, and the app is breaking down during compilation, is there something else i need to configure? I am using angular 5.